# Saving XML in AS3.0

Tags: xml, flash

I´m doing a program in flash with as3.0 that loads a XML file in the begining and put it in to a var, edit some data in it and in the end i need that the program overwrite the original file.

Comment: That is nice, what is your question?

Comment: If you want to get a quality answer, you need to ask a more detailed question. Are you working on the web or desktop? Is this and AIR app or a pure Flash app? Can you run a php script? All of these details will help answer your question. There are multiple ways to save xml from the Flash Player and the only way to help you out is to know the parameters that you are working within.

Answer (score 0):

Saving Files on a local machine is only possible within an AIR Application.

Keywords:
File, FileStream, writeUTF()

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html

If you write a Flash / Flex Application that should run within the browser you have to send your xml to a server that saves it. Probably you choose some PHP Server Script to do so.

Keywords:
fwrite, file_put_contents

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php